# Objects disappear on zoom-in

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have an issue with objects disappearing on zoom-in.

If I load the model on refresh of the browser, then I do not have an issue, if I, however, have a "button" to open the model, I experience the problem.

It is not 100% constant but seems to happen mostly on models that are geometrically fairly large.

I am right now trying to run `this.viewer.fitToView(null, model, false);` on model load.

Any ideas to other way I can 'reset' or refit the camera after loading the models?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The error seemed to be because of scaling of models.
I used to run `loadOption: { applyScaling?: "mm" }` on all model loads, but are now instead only doing this option while needed.

Comment: try turn off progressive rendering (`NOP_VIEWER.setProgressiveRendering(false)` or through the settings panel) and see if that helps - if not can you put together a minimally reproducible live demo (codepen/jsbin) or send over the offending model (upload to dropbox/gdrive etc and send the link to forge.help@autodesk.com) so we can look into it?

Comment: I tried turning off progressive rendering but get the same results. I will try to send you one of the files I have problems with.
It should maybe be mentioned that the zoom-in works fine on BIM360, so it must be a forge/My code ting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others in a similar situation, I did some more testing, and for sure seemed to be an issue with the scaling.

If you are in a situation like I was where all models needed scaling to fit together, I would for sure go for meters instead of millimeters, this seems to give far fewer issues - I assume that all coordinates been significantly smaller numbers helps everything about navigation more smooth.

Therefore, if needed, use `loadOption: { applyScaling?: "m" }`